# Please explain the proof of law of total probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I don't really understand how to derive the proof for the Law of Total probability. In this example, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Total_Probability_Theorem, I'm not sure what the enlarged union symbol means and how they got the proof overall.

Comment: You are probably familiar with indexed sum notation, e.g., $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i = a_1+a_2+a_3$.  The big union is the same idea, e.g. if I have three sets $A_1, A_2, A_3$, then we can write their union as $\bigcup_{i=1}^3 A_i$. The notation $\bigcup_i$ just means to union over all the appropriate values of $i$.

Comment: If it helps, try to go through the proof in the case that the partition has two elements and then explicitly write the union as $B_1 \cup B_2$ and see how the proof proceeds. After you understand the proof for a partition of size two, try to understand the generalized version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcup\limits_i B_i$ means simply $B_1\cup B_2\cup \ldots$.

The family of events $B_1, B_2,\ldots$ is a partition of $\Omega$. It means that this evens are disjoint such that $B_1\cup B_2\cup \ldots=\Omega$.

For any event $A$, 
$$
A=A\cap \Omega = A\cap (B_1\cup B_2\cup \ldots) = 
(A\cap B_1)\cup (A\cap B_2)  \cup \ldots.
$$
The events $A\cap B_1, A\cap B_2, \ldots$ are disjoint since $B_i$ are disjoint.

Countable additivity property of probability give: 
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P((A\cap B_1)\cup (A\cap B_2) \cup \ldots)=\mathbb P(A\cap B_1)+\mathbb P(A\cap B_2)+\ldots.
$$

Next use conditional probability definition: $\mathbb P(A|B_i)=\dfrac{\mathbb P(A\cap B_i)}{\mathbb P(B_i)}$ which leads to chain rule for each summand in (\ref{1}): $$\mathbb P(A\cap B_i)=\mathbb P(B_i)\cdot \mathbb P(A|B_i).$$

Finally, 
$$
\mathbb P(A) = \mathbb P(B_1)\cdot \mathbb P(A|B_1)+\mathbb P(B_2)\cdot \mathbb P(A|B_2)  + \ldots.
$$